# Android beginner:how to detect specific position on imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event

I am android beginner.I want to detect specific position on the image so i trigger a function on respective touch. Different mobile have different density so i can not use as pixel for triggering a function.so what are option that i select in my program.

Comment: Have you tried using percentage, xPercentage=(currentX/noOfPixelInWidth)*100, yPercentage=(currentY/noOfPixelsInHeight)*100

Answer (score 1):

Use a View.OnTouchListener:

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mE){ 
        switch (mE.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                int positionTouchedX =  mE.getRawX();
                int positionTouchedY =  mE.getRawY();
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you the coordinates that the user has touched the screen at.  You could use getResources to get your drawable size or whatever is being used in your view to find how those x,y coordinates correspond to a position on your image.

Comment: but if the screen density of mobile is changed then that will work

Comment: according to the screen density image will strecth him self  so the pixel postion will be change ....for every device

Comment: ya, that's why you specify different images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc